# angularFireAuth.signInWithPopup not working in Web View of Mobile Apps

Tags: angular, firebase, google-oauth, angularfire2, angularfire

I have an Angular Web App that User [AngularFire Auth](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md) which is a Angular plugin for Firebase.

I am using the below code to login with Google:

```
this.angularFireAuth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
.then(
  // login success
  userInfo => {
      console.log(userInfo);
      alert(`Welcome ${userInfo.user.displayName}`)
      this._router.navigate( [''] )
   },
      // login fail
      error => {
        alert('Login failed. Please try again.')
      }
)
```

The login works well when opened in a regular Desktop or Mobile browser but when I open the link from Instagram or TikTok ads which open an inner Web View Window the login is not working.

I see the below error when opening the link from IOS Instagram App:

```
Eroare 403: disallowed _useragent
You can't sign in from this screen because this app doesn't
comply with Google's secure browsers policy. If this app has
a website, you can open a web browser and try signing in
from there.
You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't
comply with Google's secure browsers policy.
```

[image]

Is there a solution for this? Basically people who click the link in ads of a mobile app they can't create an account through Google.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I'm facing the same

Comment: No, I haven't.
I just added a text telling visitors that if they are viewing the Web page in a Mobile app they should open the following address in regular browser